# MarkLogic - Create multiple field search codes at a time & search is not working

Tags: indexing, field, marklogic

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

In dev environment We created 5 fields (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5) one by one i.e. each index took around 20 hrs for 19M records and search was working fine.

For System Test environment, we created 5 fields at a time in same sequence and MarkLogic took around 3 days to finish indexing for 19M records.

But then search was working for only Field1 and not for others. We tried everything but nothing worked out and then we restarted all ML servers and it started working.

For UAT environment, we created Field2 1st and then Field1, Field3, Field4, Field5. So in UAT, Field2 started working and not others and after we restarted, it started working.

So it seems, like 1st Index is enabled after ML is done with Indexing but for others it not, but not sure why restart is required.

Field index
[image]

Comment: Field indexes do not need to be created one at a time. You can create all 5 of them at the same time and then allow enough time for the database to reindex and the fields to become available. Restart should not be required. It would be helpful if you posted details about these field indexes in the question, but if you have access to MarkLogic Support you could open a support case to help work through your issues/questions.

Comment: Hello Hansen, Thanks for your reply. Yes, we waited till MarkLogic status page says "Reindexing/Refragmenting State: Not reindexing/refragmenting " and after that also we waited for 2 days (as we are not sure why it is not working, so might be some internal processing). I have added screenshot for Field index in question.

Comment: The path (which you blacked out) would be the most relevant information, and it would be helpful to have that for all of the indexes (especially the ones that are not working). Also, post code and data instead of screenshots (on the 8002 status pages, there are links for JSON or XML formatted, instead of the default HTML rendering).

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided the path information for the indexes, so it is difficult to tell, but looking through the [Bug Fixed List](https://help.marklogic.com/Bugtrack/List) since **9.0-8.2**, I see a reindexing bug addressed in **9.0-11** that sounds similar to what you are describing.

> **Reindexer never finishes reindexing path field**
>
> If a path field includes an unsearchable predicate (such as a positional constraint) and a document includes the elements at the head of the path (before the unsearchable predicate) but not the element at the end of the path, the reindexer will keep reindexing that document over and over. Example: Path: `/root/branch/stem[1]/twig/leaf` Document: `<root><branch><stem>No leaves!</stem></branch></root>`
>
> BUG-53212
>
> Fixed in 9.0-11

**I would try upgrading to 9.0-11** and see if the problem goes away, especially if your path field indexes contain predicates or unsearchable expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. No, we do not have any indexes contains predicates or unsearchable expressions it is straightforward, i will add in original question. Why i am saying that this is not an issue, because it was not working on DEV & ST environment, it worked after restart.
About upgrading it to 9.0.11, i will propose and will see when it happens